# Magento Layered Navigation - Sort By Count

Tags: magento, navigation, layered

I would like to sort each of my layered navigation filters by # of items in each filter.

Here's what shows now-

- Books - 1
- CD's - 2
- DVD's - 20

What I want to show-

- DVD's - 20
- CD's - 2
- Books - 1

I've been looking at catalog/layer/filter.phtml, but I can't figure out how to sort magento collections.

Ideally I want something like this:

$this->getItems()->order('Count Desc')

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

Found the way to do this-

Modified `Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php` to re-sort using count in the `getItems` method.

```
public function getItems()
{
    if (is_null($this->_items)) {
        $this->_initItems();
    }

    //5-16-11 Custom sort
    $items = $this->_items; 
    usort($items, array("Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract", "sortByCount"));  
    return $items;
}

public static function sortByCount($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->getCount() == $b->getCount()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->getCount() > $b->getCount()) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: It's Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php. Not Mage/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start is Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php. The list is built there..